# Question based on application of Cauchy's Inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

This is question 9 of textbook Punnusamy and Silvermann on page 273( section Cauchy's Inequality).

[image]

I have done (a) but I don't know how to do (b). Problem is that I am not sure on how to use inequality here. I am not sure on how should I proceed so that I get term involving $(1-r) ^2 $ in denominator.

Please give hint on how to attempt.

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Schwarz Pick inequality will nicely do for b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall from Cauchy's formula that $f(w)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-w}d\zeta$ for $|w|<1.$ Use this to obtain
$$f(z_2)-f(z_1)=\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C}f(\zeta)\frac{z_2-z_1}{(\zeta-z_1)(\zeta-z_2)}d\zeta.$$

Dividing both sides by $(z_2-z_1),$ putting an absolute value we easily see that $$\left|\frac{f(z_2)-f(z_1)}{(z_2-z_1)}\right|\le \frac{1}{(1-r)^2},$$

where we used the fact that $|f(\zeta)|\le 1$ and $|(\zeta-z_1)(\zeta-z_2)|\ge (1-r)^2.$

Comment: There is a mistake in line 1 in cauchy formula

Comment: @Ben  And, what exactly is the mistake?

Comment: It should be f(z) instead of f(w).

Comment: Ohh! I see! Thanks. I will fix it.